# Invalid SOAP message when connecting Amazon AWSECommerceService

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-services, cxf

I try to connect to Amazon AWSECommerceService. I generated client classes using CXF and provided WSDL, but I get an error "The action itemLookup is not valid for this endpoint".

Some investigation brought me to this point:
Generated SOAP message is like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:itemLookup
            xmlns:ns1="http://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/">
            <ItemLookup
                xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
                <AssociateTag>pkd</AssociateTag>
                <Request>
                    <IdType>ISBN</IdType>
                    <ItemId>0321534468</ItemId>
                    <SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
                </Request>
            </ItemLookup>
        </ns1:itemLookup>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but it is supposed to be:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
            <ItemLookup
                xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
                <AssociateTag>pkd</AssociateTag>
                <Request>
                    <IdType>ISBN</IdType>
                    <ItemId>0321534468</ItemId>
                    <SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
                </Request>
            </ItemLookup>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It looks that there is one unexpected tag

```
<ns1:itemLookup
                xmlns:ns1="http://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/">
```

The second example works well when using SoapUI.
What did go wrong? What am I missing running wsdl2java maven plugin?

Please forgive me if question is stupid. I'm really new to webservices and SOAP.

When I added annotation:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

I got the message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:itemLookup
            xmlns:ns1="http://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/">
            <ns2:ItemLookup
                xmlns:ns2="http://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/"
                xmlns:ns3="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
                <AssociateTag>pkd</AssociateTag>
                <Shared>
                    <IdType>ISBN</IdType>
                    <ItemId>0321534468</ItemId>
                    <SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
                </Shared>
            </ns2:ItemLookup>
        </ns1:itemLookup>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Those namespaces are weird for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I don't know why it acted like this, but the problem was in the way I created the service:

```
ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(AWSECommerceServicePortType.class);
factory.setAddress("https://soap.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService");
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
AWSECommerceServicePortType ss = (AWSECommerceServicePortType) factory.create();
```

But when I changed this to:

```
AWSECommerceServicePortType ss = new AWSECommerceService().getAWSECommerceServicePort();        
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(ss);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

it worked. Thanks @SRT_KP for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

In the package where your ItemLookup.java file resides, verify if there exists package-info.java, if not create one. And in the package-info class your code would look like

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "hhttp://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://_2011_08_01.awsecommerceservice.webservices.amazon.com/", prefix = "ns1")
})
package your.package;
```

So try to remove the namespace uri

Opps wrongly interpreted your question. Here is the solution

Add Annotation

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

To your class

Comment: Which one? The service itself or ServicePortType class? I'll check the solution at home in the evening, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It didn't work :(. The message changed, but not the way expected.